# Why I cant create in DOM anchor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this javascrpt code:

```
    for (var data in feature.data) {
        if (!shownParameters[data]) continue;

        var xmlString = "<a href='www.cnn.com'>Link</a>"
        var elem = $.parseHTML(xmlString);

        var item = $("<li>", { style: 'padding:0px;text-align:right' })
            .append($('<div>')
                .append($("<span>", { text: elem }).addClass("view"))
            .addClass("feature-data-value"))
            .append($("<div>").addClass("clear-div"));
        item.appendTo('#wfs-details-list');
    }
```

In code above I try want to create anchor link DOM element.
But in the view I get this:

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

Any idea why I cant create in the DOM anchor link elelment?

Comment: You're assigning your element to the `text` property. That's going to force it to be interpreted as a plain string. Just use `.append(elem)` to directly append it.

Comment: Also why not just create the anchor element with jQuery the same way you're creating all the other elements??

Comment: `href='www.cnn.com'` is a page-relative link to something that's likely not local...

Comment: I am new to web can you show please example?

Comment: @Michael Pointy pretty much told you precisely what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually, this is not true way, but resolve your issue..

```
  for (var data in feature.data) {
        if (!shownParameters[data]) continue;

        var xmlString = "<a href='http://www.cnn.com'>Link</a>";
        var item = $("<li>", {style: 'padding:0px;text-align:right'})
            .append($('<div>').append($("<span>").append(xmlString)).addClass("view"))
            .addClass("feature-data-value")
            .append($("<div>").addClass("clear-div"));
        item.appendTo('#wfs-details-list');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming to create this:

```html
<ul id="wfs-details-list">
  <li style="padding:0px;text-align:right" class="feature-data-value">
    <div class="view"><span><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Link</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear-div"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

then this is clearer but not shorter

```js
for (var data in feature.data) {
  if (!shownParameters[data]) continue;
  $("<li>", {
      style: 'padding:0px;text-align:right', // belongs in a class
      class: "feature-data-value"
    })
    .append(
      $('<div>', {
        class: "view"
      })
      .append(
        $("<span/>").append(
          $("<a/>", {
            href: "http://www.cnn.com",
            text: "Link"
          })
        )
      )
    )
    .append($("<div/>", {
      class: "clear-div"
    }))
    .appendTo('#wfs-details-list');
}
```